# Умножение двух матриц 100х100 (многопоточность)

Tags: python, многопоточность, матрицы, семафоры

Столкнулся с такой задачей: нужно умножить две матрицы размером 100х100, при этом используя метод синхронизации потоков - СЕМАФОР. Не до конца понял как нужно работать с семафором.
Смог переделать свой код для умножения матриц. Но вопрос остается открытый: как к этому добавить многопоточность.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0, 10000).reshape(100, 100)
b = np.arange(10000, 20000).reshape(100, 100)
print(np.dot(a, b))
```

Прошу, подскажите, как можно реализовать такое?

Comment: Это учебное задание на освоение многопоточности и семафоров? Если да, то есть смысл. А если это реальная потребность в быстром умножении матриц, то это тупиковый путь.

Comment: Alexander Petrov под тупиковым путём имел ввиду, что можно использовать готовое решение из библиотеки Numpy, если вам не обязательно самому реализовывать умножение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, это учебное задание.

Comment: Я просто не понимаю каким образом можно реализовать семафор на пайтоне и при этом связать данное с умножением матриц.

Comment: уже не чем, я его изменил, добавив новый код умножение. Но разобраться с семафорами не вышло(

Comment: Есть ли требование на количество потоков? Так-то семафор в питоне: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects Но в этой задаче есть пара минусов: GIL и семафор. Из-за GIL выигрыша от использования потоков не будет (и по идеи, благодаря нему и семафор не нужно будет использовать), разве что вместо потоков в отдельные процессы помещать выполнение...

Comment: А так, создаете еще матрицу такого же размера, создаете сколько нужно потоков, например, 2 потока: 1) перебирает от начала до середины матриц 2) перебирает от середины до конца матрицы. Единственное, непонятно куда тут воткнуть семафор, ибо он тут, по-мне, нафиг не нужен. Хотя единственное что остается - в коде, что у новой матрицы делает присваивание значением из умножения

Comment: мне разрешено использовать 5 потоков. Я не до конца понял что Вы имеете ввиду перебирать матрицу и для чего это нужно. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @arnold, для начала вам нужно вручную повторить алгоритм переумножения матриц, чтобы понять алгоритм и знать какие операции можно делать параллельно. Накидал пример, пока сам вспоминал алгоритм: https://pastebin.com/pfX5WLF3

Comment: @gil9red на каконичном алгоритме некуда воткнуть семафор. надо искать более быстрый алгоритм наверное

Comment: если суммирование распараллелить, то семафор нужен будет при слиянии

Comment: @RomanKonoval точно! хотя на данной задаче только сумашедший пойдет распаралеливать сумму, когда есть 2 прелесных цикла)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так можно распаралелить первый цикл на каноничном алгоритме:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

a = np.arange(0, 10000).reshape(100, 100)
b = np.arange(10000, 20000).reshape(100, 100)

N = 100
c = np.zeros((N,N))

def forcolumn(i):
    row = np.zeros((1,N))
    for j in range(N):
        row[0,j] = sum(a[i, k] * b[k, j] for k in range(N))
    return i,row

pool = mp.Pool()

for i,row in pool.imap_unordered(forcolumn, range(N), N//os.cpu_count()//2):
   c[i,:] = row[0,:]

print(c)
```

Семафор воткнуть некуда.

Comment: можете подробнее рассказать про Ваш код, и почему не получается здесь использовать семафор? Хочу вникнуть в данную задачу.

Comment: он тут не нужен просто. потоки и так семафорятся на каждой функции питона (GIL), а процессы эффективней запускать через пул.

Ваша задачка поставленна для другого языка или для другого алгоритма.

Comment: спасибо! И ещё одно, не знаю почему но Ваш код у меня не запускается(

Comment: @arnold попробуйте найти и реализовать оптимизированный алгоритм. Википедия говорит что есть ещё 5 алгоритмов - для того чтоб воспользоваться семафором нужно чтоб значение в ячейке С зависило от значения С

Comment: У меня запускается. Может не установлен Нампи? Хотя Вы им пользуетесь) ....если  будет не лень чуть позже перепишу без нампи.

Comment: нет, у меня всё установлено, но при запуске, компилятор циклично выдает ошибки.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyQej.png у меня без ошибок. python 3.9

Comment: Напишите https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Штрассена на питоне в вопрос - посмотрим как его распаралелить

Comment: Сейчас создам вопрос)

Comment: да можно продолжить в этом

Comment: Этот алгоритм рекурсивный) опять семафон не нужен(((

Comment: хотя сначала давай посмотрим что в одном потоке выйдет

Comment: не могли бы Вы объяснить, каким образом работает многопоточность? И как вообще можно её использовать в данном случае. Не могу разобраться(

Comment: в питоне она не работает)