# Умножение двух матриц 100х100 (используя многопоточность)

Tags: python, многопоточность, матрицы, семафоры

Столкнулся с такой задачей: нужно умножить две матрицы размером 100х100, при этом используя метод синхронизации потоков - СЕМАФОР. Не до конца понял как нужно работать с семафором. Смог переделать свой код для умножения матриц. Но вопрос остается открытый: как к этому добавить многопоточность.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0, 10000).reshape(100, 100)
b = np.arange(10000, 20000).reshape(100, 100)
print(np.dot(a, b))
```

Прошу, подскажите, как можно реализовать такое?

Comment: А чем ваш вопрос отличается от предыдущего вашего https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1347074/?